# Big Spender VIP

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

When do you use the "Big Spender" VIP? While orders are being placed, or when all slots are stocked? I keep getting this VIP and don't really know when to utilize him.

Answer (score 3):

Send a Big Spender VIP to a floor that has stock and he will buy out one of the stocked items immediately.  So if the item has 9,000 left in stock and is sells to bitizens for 3 imperial credits each, that nets you 27,000 imperial credits -- immediately.

Some notes on how to best take advantage of this VIP:

1. Send it to a level that has a lot of stock so the payoff is large.  Something like a Bounty Hunter or Rancor Pit level.  I use all my Upgrader VIPs on these levels so the payoff from Big Spender VIPs is even larger
2. Since you can't control which of the stocked items he will buy, only send him to a level that has the 3 credit goods stocked.  If you only have those in stock, then that is all he can buy.

Comment: Thank you much for the information I really appreciate it. Now it has been totally De-mystified much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use them when the items are already stocked.

In other words, you deliver this VIP to a floor which has stock, and he buys out the entire stock of one item.

If the items are not stocked, he has nothing to buy.

Answer (score 0):

He will randomly purchase the entire stock of one in-stock item (the same as if you spend bux on the "sell now" buttons. The best use is to wait until you've just stocked the 3-credit item in a floor with large amounts of stock, and that's the only item there. For example, the 3-credit item in the Trash Compactor stocks over 10k items with a dream jobber, depending on upgrade levels. If you stock that, send the Big Spender there, and there's nothing else for him to randomly buy, he'll send 30,000 credits straight your way.